# How can I set the default double click action in Server Explorer?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, server-explorer

In Visual Studio 2012 (and previous versions), if you double click a table in the Server Explorer the table design view opens.

I rarely use this, as I am not responsible for the database definition in my current project.

What I would like to have as the default open behaviour is "view table data" instead.

Is there a way to change the behaviour of double clicking a database table in Server Explorer? I was unable to find the setting in the VS options.

Comment: Sure would be great! (Although I'm using VS 2015 these days)